# Django How to add level into select multiple

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

This is a very difficult question, that I am not able to answer.

I have three classes, TestSubject can have more than one subject and one module can have more than one subject.

```
class Module(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Subject(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module)

class TestSubject(models.Model):
    id =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
```

In the TestSubject admin form, I can have multiple select textbox for subject shown below:

```
**module1 
  *subject1
  *subject2
**module2
  *subject3
  *subject4
```

So when useer select module1, it will automatically select all the subjects in the same module, for example, when I select module1, subject 1 and 2 is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could [override the choices](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany) for your subject-field in your TestSubject `ModelAdmin` so that it reflects the structure you need. 
Though eventually [tweaking the m2m-widget is enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182996/django-display-nested-categories-in-admin-multiple-select/4211172#4211172).

To select multiple entries at once you should look at some ajax-enhanced widgets.

[Ajax Filtered Fields](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-filtered-fields/#4.4%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0) is an option that could be possibly tweaked to do what you want.